# run launch.json profile via CLI

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a maven SpringMVC project inside the project I have a `launch.json` file like this `.vscode/launch.json`. This `launch.json` has profiles like this

```
{
   "type":"java",
   "name":"myDemoApp - run local",
   "request":"launch",
   "mainClass":"au.com.demoApp.spring.MyDemoApp",
   "projectName":"myDemoApp",
   "vmArgs":"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8099 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dspring.security.jwt.tokenExpTime=1440 -Dspring.security.jwt.refreshTokenExpTime=2160 -DdemoApp.root.dir=/Users/admin/Desktop/myApp/demoApp-test-data"
}
```

I can simply click on debug button in vscode to run this but then I need to keep vscode open for this. I don't want that.

How can I run this from command line?

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10979 (Suggestion: Start VSCode debugger from the command-line
#10979)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the java command that can be used to run the profile.

```
java --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar -Dedval.root.dir=/Users/admin/Desktop/myApp/demoApp-test-data -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

If you want to run on an application like a `.war` file then follow below steps -

- first build the application using a `mvn` command `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -B -U -pl SpringMVC -am`
- Now use this `.war` present in target folder to run your application on localhost, like this

  `java --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar -Dedval.root.dir=/Users/admin/Desktop/myApp/demoApp-test-data -Dspring.profiles.active=local SpringMVC/target/SpringMVC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`